# Meta tags related to tagging need to be merged

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Here on meta we have [tag](/questions/tagged/tag), [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging), [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging), and a whole bunch of [other, similar tags](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/tags) (search for 'tag') that should be merged into one, preferably [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging).

Comment: Done and done. That was easy.

Comment: @jcolebrand - Thank you. How about [meta-tag:retag-request]?

Comment: eh, I think that one stands on its own as a special need. However, let me look at that and see if I can do magic :p